# Overlaying a contour plot on an image with Tkinter on grid

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, overlay

I would like to combine two images in a single GUI, but I want the combining to happen after I click a button.  I'm using a grid structure to format the GUI, and employing Tkinter. The image is imported and placed using:

```
label2 = ttk.Label(tab2)
image2 = PhotoImage(file="worldna.gif")
label2['image'] = image2
label2.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4)
```

Some database processing is done, and when I press a button, I get a contour plot. The contour is built using 3 vectors -- lat, lon, and data:

```
x = avglon; y = avglat; z = avgmeas
# Set up a regular grid of interpolation points
xi, yi = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 150), np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 150)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
# Interpolate
rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, function='cubic')
zi = rbf(xi, yi)
plt.imshow(zi, vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max(), origin='lower',
           extent=[x.min (), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
plt.set_adjustable('box-forced')           # Eliminate white space around  image
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z)
plt.show()
```

I would like to apply a 60% transparency to the interpolated scatter plot, and overlay it onto "worldna.gif". Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of multiple SO questions.  Search `[tkinter] image transparency`.  I selected the first response to that query, which has two answers.  Summary: tk does not compose images; use external package, such as `pillow`.

Comment: I think my question is still relevant. I'm trying to plot contour data over an image, not overlap two images -- the data is never saved or loaded as an image.   I understand your response regarding composing images, but this was not my question.

Comment: I marked as duplicate because you specified transparency processing, which tk does not do.  For that I believe you will have to turn the plot into an external image.  You could try to semi-simulate blending with dots and lines over an image.  What I am not sure about is whether the white space of dotted lines will be white or let a background image show.  If the former, you could plot lines as individual dots, but I expect that the dots would be solid colors and not blended with the backgound.  Using pillow for true blending seems easier.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, Thank you for your input -- is there another method that I may not be thinking of, to overlay data on top of an image? The image is a satellite image of the earth. It's tempting to use `basemap` for this, but they do not provide the realistic imagery I am looking for.

Comment: I suppose this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073386/how-do-you-directly-overlay-a-scatter-plot-on-top-of-a-jpg-image-in-matplotlib#5073509