# I'm trying to know how I can use 'extent' in matplotlib to make my background image look decent

Tags: python, matplotlib

No matter what values I change it's always distorting it, or it's too far on the left.

Here's an example:

[image: Plot with background image]

```
barchart = pd.read_csv('barchart.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(barchart)
var1 = df['col1'].head(7).tolist()
var2 = df['col2'].head(7).tolist()
sometitle = df['sometitle'][0]
var2 = [ float(x) for x in var2 ]

y_pos = np.arange(len(var1))
datafile = cbook.get_sample_data('/path/to/watch.jpg', asfileobj=False)
im = image.imread(datafile)

plt.imshow(im, zorder=0, extent=[0.5, 8.0, 1.0, 7.0])

barlist = plt.barh(y_pos, var2, align='center', alpha=0.5)
colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "pink", "cyan", "yellow"]
for a, b in zip(range(6), colors):
    barlist[a].set_color(b)
plt.yticks(y_pos, var1)

plt.xlabel('a label', color="green", fontsize=9)
plt.title(sometitle + " " + str(now)) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can anyone suggest a way to just add a background image to something like this: matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/barh_demo.htm‌​l without messing with any of the data in any way. I found a really simple example of how to do this with a scatterplot right here on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5073487/6007101 but when I tried it with Barh the image just pushed everything out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation,

> extent : scalars (left, right, bottom, top), optional, default: None
>
> The location, in data-coordinates, of the lower-left and upper-right corners. If None, the image is positioned such that the pixel centers fall on zero-based (row, column) indices.

So if you want to put the image at a given `x`, `y` with `size` all in data-coordinates, get the ratio of `im.shape` and use this to scale. For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

val = 3+10*np.random.random(7)  
pos = np.arange(7)+.5

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "pink", "cyan", "yellow"]
barlist = ax.barh(pos, val, align='center',alpha=0.5)
for a, b in zip(range(6), colors):
    barlist[a].set_color(b)

im = plt.imread('/path/to/watch.jpg')
x = 4.; y = 0.; size = 7.; xyratio = im.shape[1]/im.shape[0]
ax.imshow(im, zorder=0, extent=[x, x+size , y, y+size*xyratio])

ax.set_xlim([0.,np.max(val)+1.])
ax.set_ylim([0.,np.max(pos)+1.])

plt.show()
```

which looks like,

[image]

Note there is also the issue of whitespace around the image which will cause it to appear away from extents.

You can also do something like set `aspect="equal"` but must remove the `extents`.

Comment: Thanks, things are a little more flexible now with those options.