# How do I draw data on an imported jpeg in R?

Tags: r, image, plot, jpeg

I have imported a jpeg and I would like to put data over the top of it (the picture is a habitat and I have data of movement of an animal living in the area). I am hoping to create lines that correspond to where the animal has been recorded.

So far, I have imported the image using 'readJPEG', and have visualized my data this way (img = my imported jpeg):

```
plot(1, type="n", xlim=c(100, 150), ylim=c(300, 350)) 
rasterImage(img,100, 300, 150, 350, interpolate = TRUE)
```

Any help on how to plot data on top of this photo? I am hoping to simply use the coordinates already in place when I visualize the data (that is, the x and y tick labels indicated above).

Thank you!

Comment: So what exactly do you want to add? You should be able to add whatever you want with `points()`, `lines()`, `text()`, etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In R, how to plot with a png as background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918367/in-r-how-to-plot-with-a-png-as-background)

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993189/overlay-data-onto-background-image-in-r

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073386/how-do-you-directly-overlay-a-scatter-plot-on-top-of-a-jpg-image-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

You might find functions from the Bioconductor package *[EBImage](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/EBImage)* helpful for working with your images, as they spare you the tedious task of setting the correct coordinates etc. Once you load the image with `readImage` and `display` it, you can use R base graphics functions such as `points`, `lines`, `text` and similar to add things on top. Coordinates are set to image pixel coordinates with the origin (1,1) in the top left corner. The following example is taken from the [package vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/EBImage/inst/doc/EBImage-introduction.html).

```
library("EBImage")

f = system.file("images", "sample.png", package="EBImage")
img = readImage(f)

display(img, method="raster")
text(x = 20, y = 20, label = "Parrots", adj = c(0,1), col = "orange", cex = 2)
```

[image]