# Plot data on top of image when image and data have different sizes

Tags: python, matplotlib

There are many questions related to adding an image to a plot. However, in all these questions the data plotted on top of the image has the same size. For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073386/how-do-you-directly-overlay-a-scatter-plot-on-top-of-a-jpg-image-in-matplotlib), the scatter point are plotted directly into the picture coordinates.

What I need is something else. I have the following data (example) and the following images that I wish to combine:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(15,6), sharey=True)
axes = axes.flatten()

for ax in axes:
    x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    y = x
    ax.bar(x,y)
```

[image]

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(15,6), sharey=True)
axes = axes.flatten()

for ax, im in zip(axes,images):
    ax.imshow(im, alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Now, if I try to plot the bars and the images unto the same axis, the bars will be so small as to be invisible. See for example the effect of `set_xticks`.

```
for ax, im in zip(axes,images):
    x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    y = x
    ax.bar(x,y)
    ax.set_xticks([1,2,3,4,5])
    ax.imshow(im, alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

**Question:**

How can I plot the data on top of the images? I tried it with a `twinx` but I couldn't get that working properly.

I tried to rescale the data to fit the size of the images.

```
def scale_data(data, size):
    return [int(x/max(data)*size) for x in data]
```

But the `imshow` function also flips the y-axis. Now, I can flip the image first, then flip the y-axis myself again, rescale all the data so it fits onto the images and then set the proper width of the bars, however this all feels much to complex and I assume there is a much simpler solution that I am simply missing.

What is the best way to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot the graph on top of the image, use the extent parameter to adjust it. In this case, adjust it to match the x-axis of the bar chart. As an example, we use an image from the official [reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_clip_path.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-image-clip-path-py). Also, subplots are not part of this assignment, so we have used a single graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

with cbook.get_sample_data('grace_hopper.jpg') as image_file:
    image = plt.imread(image_file)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = x
ax.bar(x, y)

im = ax.imshow(image, extent=[0,5.5,0,5.5])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty good. But this only works if the axis are equal. What if the x-range is larger/smaller then the y-range?